# Flash (as3) runs slower in browser than in standalone

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash

I have made a custom video player in Flash built on the AS3 Netstream. In development it was never causing any significant CPU usage: Youtube/Vimeo are at about 10 to 15% CPU and my own player 20 to 25%.

Now it's running on our development webserver and it is hogging the CPU.

[image]

I have tried setting the framerate unreasonably low (1fps) and it doesn't seem to make any significant impact.

We have experimented with WMODE in the HTML page that runs the player. In `wmode: "direct"` it is a little better, but still nowhere close to the CPU amount in FlashDevelop.

I will gladly post all the code you think is relevant but at the moment I am at a loss for what could be causing this.

UPDATE:

Could it be related to the video file format?

UPDATE:

I have tried Chrome and Firefox on multiple computers. CPU usage varies according to the speed of the computer, as expected, but is always about 4 or 5 times as much as any other video player. So far we have found out that the high CPU compared to other players is caused by decompressing. If a smaller video format is used it works better. However, this doesn't answer the main question: why is the CPU usage within browser(s) so much higher than in standalone Flash?

Comment: Try another browser to check if this Chrome bug.

Comment: Definitely do as alxx said and try a different browser. Chrome's self-supplied Flash plugin is abysmal, to say the least.

Comment: sorry it was supposed to say "direct", we tried all.

Comment: Just want to confirm: "standalone" means that Flash exe that runs SWF's outside the browser, right? If so, what happens if you run your SWF in Chrome/Firefox but locally (not on the webserver). I ask b/c you stated the problem happened after deploying to web server.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a difference in performance in different environments, so please check the follwing things:

- is flashdevelop using a debug or release player?
- is your browser using a debug or release player?
- does it matter if you make a release or debug build (if you use the Flash IDE, this setting is called 'permit debugging')? Test on debug player AND release player?
- are you using the chrome pepper player (buildin)?
- is your code valid, doublechecked, no runtime errors?
- did you profile the flash on memory leaks?
- are you using StageVideo? This will render video on GPU, which should give better performance (Btw youtube and vimeo does)
- did you test with other videos, bitrates, encodings?

Comment: thanks for a very thorough response. All of that checks out except StageVideo (which I'll look into) and how do I profile for memory leaks?

Comment: With flashdevelop, there is a build-in profiler. You could check if there are objects constantly being created but not destructed, the memory should be slowly raise in that case. When I look at your graph it should not be the case, but for the sake of performance its always good to check what classes/objects are active.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled the plugin-container in Firefox (in about:config, turn `dom.ipc.plugins.enabled` to `false`) and my Flex app seems to run as fast as in the standalone player now.

Comment: Thumbs up. That helps. Any idea how to achieve the same in IE?